# Excel VSTO Addin: how to remove install prompt?

Tags: wix, certificate, vsto

I'm trying to install a very simple Excel VSTO Addin (just one dll) using the WIX installer method, making sure that the "Are you sure you want to install this customization?" prompt does not show at all.

1. I've imported the certificate and exported again as a PFX without the chained informations
2. I've signed everything I could using following post-build events:

- "signtool.exe" sign /f  $(SolutionDir)Thawte.pfx /p myPwd$(TargetPath)

- "mage.exe" -sign $(TargetPath).manifest -CertFile  $(SolutionDir)Thawte.pfx -Password myPwd

- "mage.exe" -sign $(TargetDir)$(TargetName).vsto -CertFile  $(SolutionDir)Thawte.pfx -Password myPwd

3. I installed the Thawte.pfx certificate on the Local Machine, in the Trusted Root Certification Authorities

Answer (score 2):

The prompt comes from VSTO - it stores the list of approved addins in `HKCU\Software\Microsoft\VSTO\Security\Inclusion` - if your addin is not there, you can create a registry key there listing our addin. The `PublicKey` value can be extracted from your .vsto file.

Comment: This work great. However. would you know how to make it true for all users? 
I've tried the trick described here https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/mshneer/2008/04/24/deploying-your-vsto-2008-add-in-to-all-users-part-iii/, but without success

Comment: I don't think the prompt is shown for addins installed in a secured folder where only an administrator has write access, such as a subfolder of the Program Files folder.